# Total number of rows count in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is there an efficient single script to get exact number of rows count for specific tables and for specific databases? I am aware of 'select count(*) from table_name'.But wanted to know if there is a better way instead of executing that query going to each database and selecting those specific tables manually. Any thoughts and advise will be helpful. thank you

Comment: Exactly what are you asking here? How to get a row counts for all tables? A list of specific tables?

Comment: I need to know get row counts for specific tables based on specific date